# Enter your name, output before first space

Tags: c

I'm in desperate help, something that could be simple, I've over complicating things.

I need a program that inputs your name

e.g.
Input:
Enter your name: John Spencer

Output:
Your name is: John

I need it done in the most simple format without using functions etc

How would you error check this program, so when you type something without a space in it, it won't crash (Without using exception handlers)

```
char name[100];
int i = 0;
printf("Enter your name: ");
gets_s(name);

printf("First name is: ");

while (name[i] != 32)
{
    putchar(name[i]);
    i++;
}
```

Comment: Could you help me with the above code, to better shape what I need to do?

Comment: what seems to be the problem?

Comment: Just do two modifications: 1. Change `gets_s(name);` to `fgets(name, 100, stdin);`. 2. Change `name[i] != 32` to `name[i] != ' '`

Comment: `gets_s` need buffer size.

Comment: How would you error check this program, so when you type something without a space in it, it won't crash (Without using exception handlers)

Comment: `32`. Because [42](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=the+answer+to+life+the+universe+and+everything&qscrl=1) was taken

Comment: @Kenyanke You should add that comment to your question.

Comment: Hahaha @bolov, that created a big smile on my face :)

Comment: You might decide to use `<ctype.h>` and the `isalpha()` function: `while (isalpha(name[i]))`.  That test will fail on end-of-string, which is important.  Failing that, use `while (name[i] != '\0' && name[i] != ' ')`.

Comment: Yeah unfortunately I'm not allowed to use anything like that in these programs. (It's College work) which I've been going through in the past few days error checking.

Gotta do everything from scratch pretty much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In response to your comment, you can ensure that you only read to the end of the string by changing your condition to `while(name[i] != ' ' && name[i] != '\0')` (Note that I've changed these to character literals for better readability and portability (if you want to compile in a different charset, for example), if you must use numbers instead check for `0`).  While C++ has an overload of `gets_s` which does not take a buffer size, you should also add a buffer size (99 in this case) to `gets_s` as a second argument if you would like your code to compile in C.

Comment: Thank you very much :)

My brain is now re leaved of all the stress from something so simple.

Comment: I'm using gets_s for the sole purpose of my compiler.

Comment: @Kenyanke Indeed, but your question is tagged as C rather than C++ so I figured I would point it out.